# How to Stop or Pause JavaScript Animation?

Tags: javascript, animation

I had a simple JS script which takes an array of images and display them as an   animation by clicking a start button.
I am trying to stop the animation by clicking on the stop button (stop on the current image of the animation), which does not work.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = new Array("unc_prop_1dim_x1.jpg", "unc_prop_1dim_x2.jpg",
"unc_prop_1dim_x3.jpg", "unc_prop_1dim_x4.jpg", "unc_prop_1dim_x5.jpg");

var nextImage = 0;  //Index for nextImage
var timeout = 400;  //In milliseconds

function animation() {
    document.ani.src = images[nextImage];
    nextImage++;

    if (nextImage==images.length) {
    nextImage = 0;
    }
    setTimeout("animation();", timeout);

};
function stopAnimation() {
    ani.stop();
}
document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = function() {
stopAnimation();
};
</script>

<body>
<div id="main" style="width: 700px; height: 500px;">
<img src="unc_prop_1dim_x1.jpg" name="ani"/>
</div><br>
<input type="button" id="start" onclick="animation();" value="Start  Animation">
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop!">
</body>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` returns an `id` that can be used with ` clearTimeout(id);` call to stop timeout call. It would be better if you replace your setTimeout with setInterval and use clearInterval to stop invoking your animation function.

Comment: clearTimeout(id); worked for me. Thanks for your help.